# C header file The chicken or The egg problem

Tags: c, gcc, struct, typedef, meson-build

I was developing a c program (a compositor) and I suddenly ran into a problem.

**Here is the problem:**

I have two header files server.h and seat.h which consists of one struct each.

**server.h**

```
typedef struct
{
    const char *socket;
    struct wl_display *wl_display;
    struct wl_event_loop *wl_event_loop;
    struct wlr_backend *backend;
    struct wlr_renderer *renderer;
    struct wlr_compositor *compositor;
    struct wlr_output_layout *output_layout;

    Seat *seat; // the seat struct from seat.h

    struct wl_list outputs;

    struct wl_listener output_listener;
} Server;

bool init_server(Server *server);
void run_server(Server *server);
void destroy_server(Server *server);
```

**seat.h**

```
typedef struct
{
    Server *server;  // the server struct from server.h
    struct wlr_seat *wlr_seat;

    struct wl_listener input_listener;
    struct wl_listener destroy_seat;
} Seat;

Seat *create_seat(Server *server);
void handle_new_input(struct wl_listener *listener, void *data);
void destroy_seat(struct wl_listener *listener, void *data);
```

*The main problem is that it creates a loop of header files so when I compile it causes error.*

I have read about the problem in here [C header file loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146657/c-header-file-loops). And I tried this it worked in the case of struct but when I call the `create_seat()` function it is telling that the type is mismatched. In my case I'm using `typedef` too so it's a little bit confusing.

Since the actual code is not good to run on any machines (because it need dependencies and so on) please use this code as the reference, this explains my actual problem.

I uses meson build system. If I compile the program using ninja it ends in an infinite loop.

Here's the code:

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "server.h"
#include "seat.h"

int main()
{
    Server server;
    server.id=10;

    Seat seat;
    seat.id=20;

    server.seat=seat;
    seat.server=server;

    printSeatId(server);
    printServerId(seat);
    return 0;
}
```

**server.h**

```
#include "seat.h"
typedef struct
{
    Seat seat;
    int id;
} Server;

void printSeatId(Server s);
```

**seat.h**

```
#include "server.h"
typedef struct
{
    Server server;
    int id;
} Seat;

void printServerId(Seat s);
```

**server.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "server.h"
void printSeatId(Server s)
{
    printf("%d",s.seat.id);
}
```

**seat.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "seat.h"
void printServerId(Seat s)
{
    printf("%d",s.server.id);
}
```

**meson.build - in src folder**

```
sources = files(
  'main.c',
  'server.c',
  'seat.c'
)

executable(
  'sample',
  sources,
  include_directories: [inc],
  install: false,
)
```

**meson.build in project folder**

```
project(
  'sample',
  'c',
  version: '1.0.0',
  meson_version: '>=0.56.0',
  default_options: ['c_std=c11','warning_level=2'],
)

add_project_arguments(
  [
    '-DWLR_USE_UNSTABLE',
    '-Wno-unused',
    '-Wno-unused-parameter',
    '-Wno-missing-braces',
    '-Wundef',
    '-Wvla',
    '-Werror',
    '-DPACKAGE_VERSION="' + meson.project_version() + '"',
  ],
  language: 'c',
)

cc = meson.get_compiler('c')
inc = include_directories('include')
subdir('src')
```

Here is the directory structure :

```
<project_folder>
     |--->src
     |     |--->server.c
     |     |--->seat.c
     |     |--->meson.build
     |
     |--->include
     |     |--->server.h
     |     |--->seat.h
     |
     |--->meson.build
```

I have given the same directory structure of the original project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ circular header includes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11971408/c-circular-header-includes)

Comment: You can solve this issue by adding a forward declaration of the `Seat` struct before the `Server` struct or adding a forward declaration of the `Server` struct before the `Seat` struct.

Comment: can you please explain

Comment: The edited code doesn't have any logic but this is the problem that I'm facing

Comment: Caveat: The [example] does not use pointers to the respective other structure.

Comment: I just give it to show the error that's causing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to resolve the conflict is by adding a forward declaration of an incomplete structure type. The `struct` type used in the forward declaration needs a tag and the same tag is used for the complete declaration of the same type. For symmetry, it makes sense to add forward declarations of both the `Seat` and `Server` structure types. The `typedef` type definitions can be moved to one or more new header files that are included by the **seat.h** and **server.h** header files. The header files need to define *guard macros* to avoid multiple definition conflicts.

For example:

**seat_server_t.h**

```
#ifndef SEAT_SERVER_T_H__INCLUDED
#define SEAT_SERVER_T_H__INCLUDED

typedef struct Seat_s Seat;
typedef struct Server_s Server;

#endif
```

**seat.h**

```
#ifndef SEAT_H__INCLUDED
#define SEAT_H__INCLUDED

#include "seat_server_t.h"

/* Other includes for struct wl_listener, etc. here... */

struct Seat_s
{
    Server *server;
    struct wlr_seat *wlr_seat;

    struct wl_listener input_listener;
    struct wl_listener destroy_seat;
};

Seat *create_seat(Server *server);
void handle_new_input(struct wl_listener *listener, void *data);
void destroy_seat(struct wl_listener *listener, void *data);
#endif
```

**server.h**

```
#ifndef SERVER_H__INCLUDED
#define SERVER_H__INCLUDED

#include "seat_server_t.h"

/* Other #include's for struct wl_display, etc. here... */

struct Server_s
{
    const char *socket;
    struct wl_display *wl_display;
    struct wl_event_loop *wl_event_loop;
    struct wlr_backend *backend;
    struct wlr_renderer *renderer;
    struct wlr_compositor *compositor;
    struct wlr_output_layout *output_layout;

    Seat *seat; // the seat struct from seat.h

    struct wl_list outputs;

    struct wl_listener output_listener;
};

bool init_server(Server *server);
void run_server(Server *server);
void destroy_server(Server *server);

#endif
```

The new header file **seat_server_t.h** does not need to be included directly by the .c files such as **main.c**. It can be treated as for internal only by the other header files, **seat.h** and **server.h**. It could also be split into two separate header files (one for each `typedef`) if desired.

Comment: Let me check this

Comment: but this one gives a list of errors especially : invalid use of incomplete typedef ‘Server’ {aka ‘struct Server_s’}

Comment: @trickymind Does that error occur within the code shown above or elsewhere? And is there a `#include "server.h"` in the code that contains the error? There are extra `#include`s needed to make it work, such as `#include <stdbool.h>` and whatever defines all that `struct wl...` stuff.

Comment: see this for the log : https://pastebin.com/Q5Wwxk4M

Comment: @trickymind Does server.c include both server.h and seat.h?

Comment: yes it needed both because the create_seat() function in seat.h is called from server.c. i have added the link to the code here: please have a look into it : https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mycampus-release-version.appspot.com/o/boxspace.zip?alt=media&token=8005cb1d-3d22-4a35-b9f1-2c118b9e0115

Comment: @trickymind But that link seems to be the original source without any modifications similar to what I described above.

Comment: Yes that is the original source.when I applied your code I get the error that I shown above

Comment: I managed to build it myself. I added "include/seat_server_t.h" and modified "include/seat.h" and "include/server.h" as above. (Both of them need `#include "seat_server_t.h"`.) I also needed to add `#include "server.h"` to "src/seat.c" since it dereferences pointers of type `Server *`.

Comment: Let me check it onesmore

Comment: @trickymind Perhaps you forgot to change `typedef struct { ... } Server;` to `struct Server_s { ... };` in "server.h" (and a similar change for "seat.h")?

Comment: Thank you it worked ! ,i am also building an api for the compositor so i need to keep the names for struct as small as i can and so i came up with typedef. Once again thank you verymuch

Comment: Just a note: AFAIK the names of `struct`s are separated from the names of types. So the _**compiler**_ does not need to get different names, but _**we**_ as the readers of the source. A `typedef struct AnyName AnyName;` is correct C.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need a pointer to the other `struct`, you can forward-declare that one, like this:

```c
typedef struct Server Server;

typedef struct
{
    Server *server;  // the server struct from server.h
    struct wlr_seat *wlr_seat;

    struct wl_listener input_listener;
    struct wl_listener destroy_seat;
} Seat;
```

Comment: i will attach the entire source code because i use these struct in another header files also.

Comment: here is the entire source code : https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mycampus-release-version.appspot.com/o/boxspace.zip?alt=media&token=8005cb1d-3d22-4a35-b9f1-2c118b9e0115

Comment: note: I'm attaching the entire source code only because these structures has been used in multiple header files.

Comment: Oh, please don't link to external resources, I refuse to look there. Please edit your question and provide a [example] that shows the problem.

Comment: please  give me some time i will edit the question

Comment: No problem, I have time.

Comment: Well, Ian was faster than me. Well done! :-) Anyway, the second error you had was the missing guard against multiple includes.